# Visual studio 'xsd' command: file path

Tags: visual-studio, xsd, filepath

The command 'xsd' in the Visual Studio (2010) command window is not fiding my file.

Tried full path 'c:\...\etc...', tried path from project folder, tried any sub path of the full path, tried only the file name (as shown on any example in the web of the usage of the tool).

The file is inside the project inside a subfolder, like "project\schema\mySchema.xsd".

Command used

```
>Tools.Shell xsd <path\>myfile.xsd /classes
```

returns:

```
The operation could not be completed. System could not find specified file.
```

What work around can I make, how should I properly use the tool? (Am I using it wrongly?)

Comment: What is the command launched when you open the VS2010 command window?

Comment: Initially there's nothing on the command window.
(was that what you were asking?)

Comment: Well, i found a workarround. Got the xsd.exe file, pasted it on the same folder as the xsd file, and ran it on the windows Command Prompt. Classes are created.

Answer (score 1):

To find XSD.exe these days, go to:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.7.2
>   Tools\xsd.exe

Step by step:

- Go to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\`
- Click latest version (e.g. `v10.0A`)
- Click Bin
- Select latest .NET Version e.g. `NETFX 4.7.2 Tools`
- There is `xsd.exe`

Answer (score 0):

When you launch the shortcut that opens the Visual Studio Command Prompt you execute a batch file that set some important string inside the PATH environment variable. These strings contain the folder names where the XSD tool is located.

The shortcuts are located in this folder on my dev PC with Visual Studio 2013

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\Shortcuts
```

The shortcut that opens the Command Prompt for Visual Studio x86 Native Tools is something like this

```
%comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" x86
```

So, unless your installation is damaged you should be able to find the correct command in the relative directory of your Visual Studio 2010 install.